# Show that $\sigma(n)$ is odd if $n$ is a power of two.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that $\sigma(n)$ is odd if $n$ is a power of two.

What I know: Since $n$ is a power of two we can say $n=2^x$. So $\sigma(n)=\sigma(2^x)=2^{x+1}-1$ which is clearly odd. This identity was given and proved by the reader in Elementary Number Theory by Dudley. Is this correct? It seems too obvious.

Also $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of all the divisors of $n$.

Comment: It is correct.  Another way would be to say that $2^x$ has only one odd divisor, namely $1$, so the sum of divisors must be odd

Comment: This is a possible step in showing that $\sigma(n)$ is odd if and only if $n$ is a square number or twice a square number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct, yes, but you can prove it easily. If $n=2^k$, then the divisors of $n$ are $1,2,2^2,\ldots,2^k$ and so$$\sigma(n)=\sum_{j=0}^k 2^j=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2-1}=2^{k+1}-1,$$which is odd, as you noticed.

Comment: Thank you! I like this approach too. Can this identity also be proved using PMI?

Comment: What is PMI. Do you mean induction? If so, then, yes, it can.

Comment: Yes, Principle of Mathematical Induction.

Comment: @BarryCipra Actually, what I meant was “correct, yes”. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lemma that states, for $p$ prime, $\sigma(p^k) = \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}$. As long as you can use that, your proof would look like this:

Let $n = 2^k$, for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we have that $\sigma(n) = \sigma(2^k) = \frac{2^{k+1} - 1}{2 - 1} = 2^{k+1} - 1$, which is odd.